# MS program in Canada with bad undergraduate result

Tags: masters

I am not sure if this the appropriate place to ask such question. I have very bad undergraduate record with a CGPA of 2.40 which took nearly 6 years to complete. I have never thought to study again after my bachelor. But recently I am kind of desperate to do higher study. I attended for GRE, and  my score was 305 and my IELTS score is 7. I have 5 years of job experience as a software engineer. Is there any chance that I can get admission for MS in any Canadian university? I am kind of desperate to change my career path, I want to be an AI researcher. Is there any hope for me to pursue a masters degree in Canada or any north American country?

Answer (score 1):

I'll be blunt, you have no chance. AI is probably the most competitive field in the world right now, and most applicants have exceptionally strong profiles and still get rejected. At the University of Toronto, most people who get accepted have 3.8+ GPAs, and have at least one publication at NIPS or ICML, on top of extensive research experience.

If you're really deadset on grad school, I'd the following:

1) Apply to course based masters instead of research based masters. These are significantly easier to get into. However, you get no funding usually and are expected to pay your tuition fees and living costs yourself.

2) Apply to a field other than AI, something fairly obscure with little competition. You have 0% of getting into AI.

3) Apply to low tier schools. You're not getting into U of T or UBC in Canada for instance. Maybe try Laurier and schools in that league.

4) Your GRE score is exceptionally poor, fix it. You need to redeem your low GPA somehow. Aim for atleast 164 Quant.